# Error migrating files from CSV

Tags: migrations, 9

I'm trying to migrate a csv file that I build from a drupal 6 site.

I have create a view to export those fields:
`"fid","filemime","filename","image_path","changed","estado"` 
, "estado" is "status" field.

I have check the /web/core/file/migratrions/, also I have read: https://understanddrupal.com/lessons/migrating-files-and-images-drupal/, and some other blog post.

```yaml
My file.yml is:

# Every migration that references a file by Drupal 6 fid should specify this
# migration as an optional dependency.
id: project_files
label: Public files
audit: true
migration_group: files
audit: true
migration_tags:
  - Drupal 7
  - Files
source:
  plugin: 'csv'
  path: public://csv/files/files.csv
  delimiter: ','
  enclosure: '"'
  header_offset: 0
  constants:
    # The tool configuring this migration must set source_base_path. It
    # represents the fully qualified path relative to which URIs in the files
    # table are specified, and must end with a /. See source_full_path
    # configuration in this migration's process pipeline as an example.
    source_base_path: 'https://domain.es/sites/domain.prod1.domain.es/files/'
    file_directory_path: 'public://old_yaq'
    temp_directory_path: '/tmp'
    is_public: true
  ids:
    - fid
process:
  # If you are using this file to build a custom migration consider removing
  # the fid field to allow incremental migrations.
  fid: fid
  filename: filename
  source_full_path:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source:
        - constants/source_base_path
        - image_path
    -
      plugin: urlencode
  destination_full_path:
    plugin: file_uri
    source:
      - image_path
      - constant/file_directory_path
      - constant/temp_directory_path
      - constant/is_public
  uri:
    plugin: file_copy
    source:
      - '@source_full_path'
      - '@destination_full_path'
  filemime: filemime
  # No need to migrate filesize, it is computed when file entities are saved.
  # filesize: filesize
  status: estado
  # Drupal 7 didn't keep track of the file's creation or update time -- all it
  # had was the vague "timestamp" column. So we'll use it for both.
  created:
    plugin: date_2_timestamp
    source:
      - changed
  changed:
    plugin: date_2_timestamp
    source:
      - changed
  uid: uid
destination:
  plugin: entity:file
```

And this is my plugin

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\yaq_migration\Plugin\migrate\process;

use Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutableInterface;
use Drupal\migrate\ProcessPluginBase;
use Drupal\migrate\Row;

/**
 * Perform custom value transformations.
 *
 * @MigrateProcessPlugin(
 *   id = "date_2_timestamp"
 * )
 *
 * To do custom value transformations use the following:
 */
class DateToTimestamp extends ProcessPluginBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function transform($value, MigrateExecutableInterface $migrate_executable, Row $row, $destination_property) {

    if (empty($value[0])) {
      return time();
    }
    return strtotime($value[0]);
  }

}
```

I get this output:

```bash
wodby@php.container:/var/www/html $ drush migrate:import project_files
 [notice] Processed 2546 items (0 created, 0 updated, 2546 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'project_files'

In MigrateToolsCommands.php line 971:
                                      
  project_files Migration - 2546 failed.
```

I don't find what it's wrong.

Oskar.

Comment: Did you run `drush migrate:messages`, just try to show message

Comment: Seems timestamp is causing the issue. What format is it exported in csv ?

Comment: Try to migrate first without timestamp field and check if its migrating correctly

Comment: @Jonh I get this message: "Destination property uri not provided", also 
I have commented the date fields.

Comment: that mean, your uri field config not correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My error was here:

```yml
    source:
      - image_path
      - constant/file_directory_path
      - constant/temp_directory_path
      - constant/is_public
```

It should be `constants` this s at the end.